# Regex to allow only string but not combination of word “test”

Tags: html, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

```
^(?!test$)[a-zA-Z'.\s]{2,40}$
```

doesn't allow the word 'test' as an input, it also don't allow the numbers. How can i modify this regular expression as it will exclude all combinations of 'test'? means Test, test, TEst, tEst etc. etc. also i dont want to allow any special characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add case-insensitive modifier.

```
/^(?!test$)[a-z'.\s]{2,40}$/mi
```

or

If you don't want the word `test` to present anywhere in the input string then  you have to use the below regex.

```
/^(?!.*test.*$)[a-z'.\s]{2,40}$/mi
```

Comment: no it's not working, after using this regex it allows word 'test'

Comment: thanks. it's working on regex101, but when i put this code in jquery it doesn't work. 
$('#FirstName').attr("data-val-regex-pattern", "^(?im)(?!test$)[a-zA-Z'.\s]{2,40}$");